# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java

i have stats method using JPQL in jpa maven project , i have got that error while testing in the client project.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
public int StatDoctorBySpeciality()
 {

    int  count = 0 ;
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT  COUNT(u)  FROM User AS u where u.role like 'doctor'  GROUP BY u.specialite ");

    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
             Object[] arr =(Object[]) results.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
                count= (int) arr[j] ;

            }
            }
        return count;
}
```

Comment: `arr[j].toString()`

Comment: remove the `+ " "` would work too `System.out.print(arr[j]);
`, an exception is an object, so the `toString()` of `Object` will be call. PS : I don't see why you cast the `get` result since this is the type of your list.

Comment: the return type is Int

Comment: Wow, you use a lot of casting here then ... First, your exception say this is a Class type, not a String because it try to cast in String during the `System.out.println()` because you concat it with a String `+ " "`. Then you will have an exception because you try to cast into `int` a Class instance

Comment: the error persists even if i moved  the System.out.println()  and it still cannaot be casted to String while i don't even have a string now !

Comment: The same exact exception ? On which line ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the exception is related to the code that you are showing us? Check the stack trace for the exact file and line number!

Comment: yes it persists **java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object**   in this line    `Object[] arr =(Object[]) results.get(i);`

Comment: @RealSkeptic  yes it refers to the same code , i have cleaned my server and republish it and it persists

Comment: That's a different exception, mate. This time it just says that what you have in your list are `Long` items rather than arrays of Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a casting exception because getResultList() returns just `List <Long>` instead of `List<Long[]>`

> Ljava.lang.Long is a list of java.lang.Longs

```
public int StatDoctorBySpeciality() {
       int count =0;
    List<Long> results = em
            .createQuery("SELECT  COUNT(u)  FROM User AS u where u.role like 'doctor'  GROUP BY u.specialite").getResultList();
    for (Long result : results) {

         count = ((Number) result).intValue();
    }  
    return count ;
}
```